# Send multiple images via Email Intent

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent, arraylist

I have ArrayList with images,

```
List<Images> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new Images(R.drawable.love));
arrayList.add(new Images(R.drawable.pease));
arrayList.add(new Images(R.drawable.respect));
arrayList.add(new Images(R.drawable.nature));
arrayList.add(new Images(R.drawable.family));
```

Preparing Email intent, so far :

```
Intent send= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                send.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
//here i have to do something
                startActivity(send);
```

Is there a way how to send whole List of images via Email Intent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot get the path of the drawable resources. Store the images which can be sent in the email in some storage (internal/external) on the user device. Later on you can attach them to the email using `send .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathToImage);`

Comment: That will only attach one image. .

Comment: Google for intent.putParcelableArrayList().

Comment: `new Images()`?? What does that class do?

Comment: @greenapps class Images has constructor ,getters and setters